# Is there a way to make a drop down list expand upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: html, css

When the dropdown field don't have enough space to expand downwards, it expands upwards. This is the behavior of dropdown by default but i want it to expand always upwards.

Is there a way of doing this?

```
   <select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code that you used before?

Comment: Yes, with custom HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you provide me any links or any basics code that would be more helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/4/show/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/4/

Comment: @ShekharPankaj thanks for the help but i wanted it to be a clickable.

Comment: @SrinivasPai do whatever you want.... use click event or any thing... the above demo shows you the ideas